# Kotlin. Вынесение общих частей Activity

Tags: android, moxy

К примеру, есть 2 Активити, у которых абсолютно одинаковый BottomSheet и одинаковый код обработки нажатий (использую moxy: части Presenter, View одинаковые).

Как можно одинаковую логику вынести в отдельный класс? Суть в том, что в активити котлин биндит id элементов и есть доступ к контексту. 
Как обычно это делается? Передавать в отдельный класс контекст?